# Eclipse RCP : Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am new to Eclipse RCP. I am trying to set up a RCP project on Eclipse Juno.
After importing all the plugins into my workspace, I get the following error trying to run the application:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

May I know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.ide` needs to be in your launch configuration.

In the menu go to: Run > Run Configurations...

[image: Eclipse Launch Configuration]

In case you do not want to start the eclipse IDE but your own application, you need to change the "Main" tab of the launch "Run an application".
To create your own application search for the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point.